# Virtual host is not working in apache on remote linux server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I wrote httpd.conf file this way but it's not working for me.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ServerName dev.srv.volvo.com
    ServerAlias www.dev.srv.volvo.com

    </VirtualHost>
```

what am I doing wrong here. Please help

Comment: This is not very clear. The machine does not work at its location? Or you cannot access remotely?  Remote access needs real clarity here.

Comment: Neither of those 2 hosts exist in DNS. Either contact Volvo and ask them to update, or add them into the hosts files of every system you want to access them, but that still may not work.